# Undefined Reference Error when trying to pull data from api in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use a fake api found at *https://fakestoreapi.com/* to get data into my Next js app. But I keep getting an undefined reference error, even though I got the code snippet from the official next js docs. This is my code

```
import { Box, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
}

function ProductList() {
  return (
    <Box>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <Box>
          <Text> {product.title} </Text>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ProductList;
```

And this is the error I keep getting

```
ReferenceError: products is not defined
```

Comment: _"even though I got the code snippet from the official next js docs"_ - but not for _that_ exact kind of data structure, right ...?

Comment: No not exactly the same. But it should work either way

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function ProductList({products}) {
  return (
    <Box>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <Box>
          <Text> {product.title} </Text>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did. Now I get this error ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')```

Comment: rename the data variable to products

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Can you console.log(data) and see what is output, also console response

Comment: I commented out the ```product.map``` part and console.log the data. It didn't return anything

Comment: Can you log the response also, i think the structure of the response api is different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245753/discussion-between-syed-saad-ullah-shah-and-stephen-murya).